# I need help for a query with Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Here is a simplified schema of my Neo4j DB model.
I tried several Cypher queries based on some posts, but nothing work.

[image: My Neo4j Model Example]

I would like to find all the components and all the suppliers, for a bike number.

The complexity is that some components are linked to suppliers and in that cases, the branch is followed only if the upper component has the right version.

Examples:

- bike number 6 has component ID=3 with supplier ID=3 and component ID=1 with supplier ID=1
- bike number 1 has component ID=1 with supplier ID=2
- bike number 3 has  component ID=1 with supplier ID=2 AND component ID=2 with supplierID=3

I would like to get the nodes and the relationships.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: what about having one node per bike, give it a number. 
Have (b:Bike)-[:COMPOSED_OF]->(c:Component {reference:internalRefAtBikeMaker})-[:SUPPLIED_BY {supplierPartReference:azertyui}]->(s:Supplier {name:"SuperSupplier"})

Something like that

Comment: I would know how to query such graph if I could create it :). But I don't know how to reorganize the whole graph as it is composed of 1 millions of possible components. If you can help me to create the graph your propose from the graph I posted, it could be a solution...

Comment: Looks like you're using multiple nodes for the same supplier, in that a supplier node in your graph really symbolizes a supplier for a part, not a supplier on its own. This is also evident in your `(:Supplier)-[:IsIn]->(:Component)` relationships, since it normally would not make sense, except in the sense that the node is a supplier for a specific part. It would make more sense to say `(:Component)-[:IsIn]->(:Component)`. Do you have any flexibility to fix this data model? As it exists you also won't be able to take advantage of index lookups, so on large graphs your queries will be slow.

Comment: Do you have a typo in your sample data? That is, shouldn't `FROMBIKE=4` actually be `FROMBIKE=6` in order to get the results you indicated for Bike 6? Also, is `TOBIKE` irrelevant for this use case?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand you question. TOBIKE is relevant. This is the higher bike effectivity for wihch this component is used.

Comment: To answer to previous question, I cannot change the model. This is really old DB2 database that manages these data. I agree that the link "IsIn" is not the better solution to model a product configuration, but this is something existing

Comment: As far as I can tell, in this model the :Bike node itself (I'm assuming there's only a single :Bike node?) and relationships to its :Components are useless, as the id information for bikes is defined by ranges within relationships between :Component and :Supplier nodes. Not ideal. Seems like any solution for this model would be better off ignoring the :Bike node and its relationships completely.

Comment: As far as I can tell you haven't identified the type of the relationship between :Component and :Supplier nodes, just attributes on the relationship. Can you provide the type of this relationship? Also, will :Components only have one incoming :IsIn relationship from a :Supplier, or multiple?

Comment: You're right, there is one node Bike only. The relationships label I set between Component and Supplier is COtoSUP. But you can chosse another one.
IsIn links can be : 1 supplier to n components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, what you want is to pull all sub-graph items but filtering out relations paths that fail a filter. You can use ALL/NONE/ANY to make sure the picked up paths don't violate any constraints.

Here is an example that assumes that from and to can be defined independently, but I think it is clear enough to adjust to your needs as you like. (Note: You can use `TYPE(r)` to check the relation type name too)

```
WITH 11 as num
MATCH p=(s:Bike)-[*..25]-(n) 
WHERE 
ALL(r IN RELATIONSHIPS(p) WHERE 
    (NOT EXISTS(r.RANGEFROM) OR toInteger(r.RANGEFROM) <= num) AND 
    (NOT EXISTS(r.RANGETO) OR num <= toInteger(r.RANGETO)))
AND TYPE(RELATIONSHIPS(p)[-1]) = "LO"
WITH NODES(p) as ns, RELATIONSHIPS(p) as rs
UNWIND ns as n UNWIND rs as r
RETURN COLLECT(DISTINCT n), COLLECT(DISTINCT r)
```

Or this should be more efficient.

```
WITH 11 as num
MATCH (ci)-[lo:LO]->(ds)
WHERE toInteger(lo.RANGEFROM) <= num <= toInteger(lo.RANGETO)
WITH ds, COLLECT(lo) as lo
MATCH p=shortestpath((b:Bike)-[*..25]->(ds))
WHERE ALL(r IN RELATIONSHIPS(p) WHERE TYPE(r) <> "LO" OR r in lo)
WITH NODES(p) as ns, RELATIONSHIPS(p) as rs
UNWIND ns as n UNWIND rs as r
RETURN COLLECT(DISTINCT n), COLLECT(DISTINCT r)
```

Note: If you need better performance, you might want to look into using the Neo4J [Traversal API](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/#tutorial-traversal).

Comment: This query doesn't consider if a component has a relationships "Isin" coming from a Supplier. It doesn't answer to my need :(

Comment: @lug How does "IsIn" affect the result? The problem (as currently written) only cares about "FROMBIKE" and "TOBIKE" in an unnamed relationship. Since "IsIn" does not have either of those properties, this query should traverse it just fine. (Basically, it only checks the to/from part of a relationship if that property is defined, otherwise it defaults to true)

Comment: OK. I understand. When I run the query, I retrieve only the node Bike and the first level of component. I would need to get Bike+Components+Supplier+Components linked to supplier if existing and if the FROM and TO are in the range of the search...

Comment: @lug After the first level, every relation has a to/from filter. So you might have made an error converting the above query to match your schema (probably missed renaming a `.to` or `.from` on the right side of an OR), or an error with the actual values used.

Comment: You maybe right, but I don't see any mistake. I tried to keep your query. I removed s.id, because there is no bike ID:
MATCH (s:Bike)-[rs*..25]->(n) WHERE ALL(r IN rs WHERE (NOT EXISTS(r.FROMBIKE) OR r.FROMBIKE<= 5) AND (NOT EXISTS(r.TOBIKE) OR 5 <= r.TOBIKE)) RETURN COLLECT(DISTINCT n)+s, COLLECT(DISTINCT rs)

Comment: Isin relationships have no TO or FROM

Comment: @lug That looks correct, (and the first relations in your example don't have the to/from, so the error is in the to/from part). I would need to see the data you are testing against somehow to know exactly where it is failing, but for now, try removing the WHERE and change `[rs*..25]` to `[rs*2]` and check the results that `rs.FROMBIKE <= 5 <= rs.TOBIKE`

Comment: Which WHERE to remove ?
I tried that but with error: MATCH (s:Bike)-[rs*2]->(n) 
WHERE rs.RANGEFROM <= 5 <= rs.RANGETO
RETURN COLLECT(DISTINCT n)+s, COLLECT(DISTINCT rs)

Comment: @lug Oh, another thing to check, match the relation and do `RETURN r.FROMBIKE = 5 as isInt, r.FROMBIKE = "5" as isStr. (And remove all WHERE stuff since you want to check everything's value)

Comment: Use `toInteger(r.FROMBIKE)` to guarantee that the value is treated as an integer.

Comment: I tried : MATCH (s:Bike)-[r*2]->(n) 
 RETURN r.FROMBIKE = 5 as isInt, r.FROMBIKE = "5" as isStr. The query return an error. Is it correct [r*2] ??

Comment: @lug, `[r*2]` is var name r, match 2 times. That is the correct syntax (I tested it in mine) What error are you getting? That should be valid.

Comment: MATCH (s:Bike)-[r*..25]->(n) 
 RETURN toInteger(r.FROMBIKE)=5 as isInt, toInteger(r.FROMBIKE)=5 as isStr.
The error is on the first r.FROMBIKE : Type mismatch: expected Any, Map, Node or Relationship but was List<Relationship> (line 2, column 18 (offset: 44))
"RETURN toInteger(r.FROMBIKE) = 5 as isInt, toInteger(r.FROMBIKE) = 5 as isStr"

Comment: Oh, right. use `r[1].FROMBIKE` or change `[r*2]` to `-->()-[r]->` @lug

Comment: @lug You would get null if the property was just absent, so that mean either the next node isn't there, or the relation is in the 'wrong' direction... Try removing the `>` part of the relation to make it direction agnostic too. Are you using the web browser? Use `Match shortestpath((s:Bike)-[*..25]-(n)) RETURN *` to pull up the entire graph off of Bike.

Comment: I'm using the web browser and Match shortestpath((s:Bike)-[*..25]-(n)) RETURN * return an error : The shortest path algorithm does not work when the start and end nodes are the same.
However, the graph is clearly simple when I do Match (n) return n. Would it be possible to send you my graph ?

Comment: @lug yes, but you would either need to replicate it using http://console.neo4j.org/ and share that link, or make an export/zip of it available online (like with google drive using public share setting), and share that link.

Comment: The dump of my example DB is here:https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0Bx_1A6G-vDdqTkRUSWZpMlhROFk?usp=sharing
object name and relationships property names are a little bit different from my graphical example, but they are still very similar.
@Tezra: i it OK ?

Comment: @lug Looking at your dump, the to/from properties are Strings (in Neo4J `1=/="1"`). The can be corrected for using the toInteger() function. I updated my answer with the exact cypher I tested on the dump. (The starting WITH is just for convenience, so that I only have to change one number). I should have asked your version, but the only changes between the two versions was some deprecated warnings (I adjusted the Cypher to fix those anyways). As the cypher is now, it works exactly the way I would expect on your dump example data. Just to be safe, I have also removed the direction constraint.

Comment: It should now just be a matter of translating from the example db to the live db. Verify that this is the behavior you want on the test db though. Let me know if you have any more issues.

Comment: Yes it seems to work. I have to test on a large DB.
@Tezra : the "branches" extracted are correct except that when the triple CI-LO-DS is linked to a upper DS, the CI is return even if shouldn't.
If you try to retrieve the Bike with num=6 in my DB example, the query return the right triples CI-LO-DS but also CI number 5.

Comment: @lug Are you saying that the `DStoCI` relationship shouldn't be traversed (only RELTYPE and LO relations), or that it should only capture up to a depth of 2 (`(a)-->(b)-->(c)`)? My query will always go through DStoCI because it has no properties set. So as far as I can tell, this is the correct behavior. Your example DB is slightly different from the above picture, but if you hover over each relationship, you will see that it is valid for that given number.

Comment: DStoCI should be traversed. However, if the relationship below between a CI and a DS isn't valid, then CI linked with DStoCI and the related DS linked to this CI shouldn't be returned. Your query doesn't return DS but the CI is returned

Comment: @lug Oh, I get it now, `(ci)-[lo]->(ds)` is a triple, and they should either all return together or not at all. I've updated my answer with CI pruning (basically, make sure the last relation is a valid lo and than verify a valid trace path). I thought you wanted to capture CI and stop there if the LO was out of range.

Comment: Wahou ! It works perfectly. I'm really impressed. It is really too complex to write myself such query. I really thank you for your support !!

Comment: @lug NP. Have I answered your question thoroughly enough? :3

Comment: @lug You haven't accepted an answer, so I thought there was something else.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple data model. In addition to the `Bike`, `Component`, and `Supplier` node labels, this model adds a `Part` node label.

```
(b:Bike)-[HAS_COMPONENT]->(c:Component)-[:IS_PART]->(p:Part)
(c)-[:SUPPLIED_BY]->(s:Supplier)
```

In this model:

- A `Part` is a specific item made by a specific manufacturer, and it can be sold by any number of `Supplier`s.
- A `Bike` is made up of multiple `Component`s, each of which is a `Part` that was purchased from a specific `Supplier`.

With this model, here is a sample query to return, for a specific bike, each component part and its supplier:

```
MATCH
  (:Bike {id: 1})-[HAS_COMPONENT]->(c)-[:IS_PART]->(part),
  (c)-[:SUPPLIED_BY]->(supplier)
RETURN part, supplier;
```

Comment: Thank you for your example. Unfortunately, it doesn't help me. The bike "effectivity" is not a property of the bike but of the relationships. I cannot change the data model; it is imposed to me.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand correctly, but would this work ?

```
MATCH p=(b:Bike {bnumber = 6})-[hc:HAS_COMPONENT]-(c:Component)-[hs:HAS_SUPPLIER]-(s:Supplier)
WHERE hs.frombike >= bnumber 
  AND hs.tobike <= bnumber
RETURN p;
```

I agree with @cybersam that you could do with a simplification of the model. Do raise that concern.

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Tom

Comment: I'm surprised that the 2 proposals consider that the bike number is a property of the bike and not an attribute of the relationships. I've thought that neo4j is the right DB to parse a product structure and calculate a configuration of a product. Maybe neo4j is less powerful than I've though. No way with neo4j ??

Comment: So, enlighten us, where do you get the bike number from ? For it is no where to be found in your diagram. Is is then so strange to assume it is what identifies a bike (and thus a property of the bike) and that frombike and tobike (properties of a relationship, not attributes btw) indicate a range of those same numbers ? So please explain how you would walk your diagram to get a result !

Comment: In the diagram, Bike can be composed of 3 components : ID=1, 2 and 3.
Each component is prided by a supplier. 
To know which component is composed of what and who supply it for each bike number, the range of bike nimber is given by FROMBIKE and TOBIKE: FROMBIKE=1 means from bike number 1 and TOBIKE=5 means to bike number 5. In the example, bike 1 has only component 1 supplied by supplier 1. Component 3 is used only from bike 4 (FROMBIKE=4, TOBIKE=20). 
Problem is component 2. It has a range from 3 to 5 but it is linked to supplier 1. I must consider the range of component 1 and its range,

Comment: Now we are talking. And pray, how do you wish to start your query ? You keep referring to bike number as the identifier of a bike (and thus a property) ... but when I make that assumption ... you say it's wrong. So ... how do we start ? MATCH (b:Bike {?????}) ...

Comment: I would like all the components: match (c:component)-[r]-> (s:supplier) where r.FROMBIKE<2 AND TOBIKE>0 return c,r,s

Comment: I did a mistake in my schema, that probably doesn't help to understand :(. The TOBIKE between component=2 and supplier 3 is 6 ! So if I use my previous request for bike=6:
match (c:component)-[r]-> (s:supplier) where r.FROMBIKE<7 AND TOBIKE>5 return c,r,s, I retrieve component=3 but also component=2 that shouldn't be retrieved because of its dependency with the component=1 through the link with supplier=1 and component 1 can be only a component for bikes 1 to 5. So Component 2 mustn't be retrieved... Thank you for you supprt !